# .button("disable") is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a button called `customer-delete` and it should be disabled when customer has some information and should be enabled if customer has no such information.

my code is like this:

```
if(customer.name!=null && customer.email!=null){
    $("#customer-delete").button("disable");
    console.info("disabled");
}else{
    $("#customer-delete").button("enable");
    console.info("enabled");
}
```

but this is not working properly.
console displays it correctly so that means there is no problem with the logic, but the button is always enabled.

Can anyone give me a solution for this?

Comment: Please ensure code is formatted properly, otherwise it's harder and more annoying for helpers to read.

Comment: @user, does this button come from an actual form button or a hyperlink? Methods like `enable()`and `disable()` have no effect if the augmented element is a hyperlink.

Comment: The first sentence of your question says your button is "called" `delete-customer`, but your code uses `$('#customer-delete')` - which is it?

Comment: @ Frédéric Hamidi,
it comes from a form button, not hyperlink

Comment: @Anthony Grist,
the button is customer-delete. I have done a mistake in the first sentence

Comment: @user, any chance you have more than one element on the page with id `customer-delete`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$("#customer-delete").prop("disabled",true);
```

and [`.removeProp()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/)

```
$("#customer-delete").prop("disabled",true);
// is the same as:
$("#customer-delete").removeProp("disabled");
```

prior to jQuery version 1.6, use `.attr()`.

Or when working with jQuery UI you can hand this over as parameter-object:

```
$("#customer-delete").button({ disabled: true });
```

or after the initialisation with the setter-method:

```
$("#customer-delete").button( "option", "disabled", true );
```

EDIT:

I'm sorry for ignoring the `jquery-mobile` tag. According to the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/buttons/buttons-methods.html) your try `.button("disable")` is correct. Now there are several possibilities:

1. The doc states the following - I cannot judge from the context you gave, whether this is the case for you.

   > The following methods apply only to **form buttons**. Link-based buttons do not have any associated methods.
2. Your selector does not match correctly.
3. Conflicts elsewhere in your code.

Comment: That's fine and all, but the question is tagged `[jquery-mobile]`, and Mobile's button widget does have `enable()` and `disable()` methods (as jQuery UI's button also does, incidentally, at least until 1.9).

Comment: @Frédéric Thank you for the hint - I overlooked the tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(customer.name!=null && customer.email!=null){
    $("#customer-delete").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    console.info("disabled");
}else{
    $("#customer-delete").removeAttr("disabled");
    console.info("enabled");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(customer.name!=null && customer.email!=null){
    $("#customer-delete").attr("disabled", true);
}else{
    $("#customer-delete").attr("disabled", false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/), is it not supposed to look like this?

```
$( "#customer-delete" ).button({ disabled: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

If it has a data-role of button but is not actually a button (a link for example) you can't use those features instead;'

```
 $("#customer-delete").addClass('ui-disabled');
```